# MVT application

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I prove that if $f:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, there is a $c \in [a,b]$ such as $$\int_{a}^{c} f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} f(x)$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous, such that $F(a)=0$.

Case 1: $F(b)>0$. Then we have $F(a) < \frac{1}{2}F(b)< F(b)$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is $c \in (a,b)$ such that $F(c)=\frac{1}{2}F(b)$.

Case 2: $F(b)<0$. Then we have $F(b) < \frac{1}{2}F(b)< F(a)$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is $c \in (a,b)$ such that $F(c)=\frac{1}{2}F(b)$.

Case 3: $F(b)=0$. With $c=b$ we have $F(c)=\frac{1}{2}F(b)$.

For the above problem take $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$.

If $f$ is Riemann-integrable, $F$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

No,  if only $c \in (a,b)$ is allowed.

Let $a=0$ and $b= 2 \pi$ and $f(x)=\sin x$. Then $\frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} f(x)=0$. Now suppose that there is $c$ such that $a<c<b$ and $\int_{a}^{c} f(x)=0$. This gives $\cos c=0$, hence $c=a$ or $c=b$, a contradiction.

Comment: The OP has stated that $c\in[a,b]$, isnt it?

Comment: Yep, and f is integrable